# When user enters text in textbox then append a prefix value

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox which needs to be filled with website URL. So when user places the cursor in the textbox then the textbox should prefill with "http://" (Not a placeholder).

If the user does not enter anything and moves to the next textbox then the textbox have empty value

If the user fills the textbox then the value is unchanged

I tried below Javascript code but did not work:

```
if (document.activeElement.id == 'input-textbox-id' && !document.activeElement.value) {
            document.querySelector("#input-textbox-id").value="http://";
} else if (document.activeElement.id != 'input-textbox-id' && (!document.activeElement.value || document.activeElement.value == 'http://')) {
            document.querySelector("#input-textbox-id").value="";
}
```

Comment: can't you assign a onclick event for that text box and then add the value dynamically?

Comment: There is only the form submit button

Comment: `!document.activeElement.value` I don't think this is a valid condition since the value is not of boolean type. Anyways, if you post a code snippet, it would be helpful for debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `focus` and `blur` events for this.

Assuming that the variable `textBox` contains the reference to your textBox element, you can use the following code:

```js
let textBox = document.getElementById("a");

textBox.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  if (!this.value) {
    this.value += "http://";
  }
});
textBox.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  if (this.value == "http://") {
    this.value = "";
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a">
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to attach `event` listener by using `addEventListener`. Events you need: `focus` and `focusout`.

We add `.http-prefill` class for all inputs. We iterate over `inputs` array and attach event.

Please do not forget to remove `eventListener` when you are done eg. you unload the form.

To do so, just copy the code for adding listeners and replace `addEventListener` with `removeEventListener`.

```
inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.removeEventListener('focus', onFocus);
  input.removeEventListener('focusout', onFocusOut);
});
```

**Example code:**

```js
var fillValue = 'http://';
var onFocus = function() {
  this.value = fillValue;
}
var onFocusOut = function() {
  if (this.value === fillValue) {
    this.value = '';
  }
}

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.http-prefill');

inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('focus', onFocus);
  input.addEventListener('focusout', onFocusOut);
});
```

```css
.http-prefill {
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input class="http-prefill" name="input-0" />
<input class="http-prefill" name="input-1" />
<input class="http-prefill" name="input-2" />
<input class="http-prefill" name="input-3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some key events like onKeyDown and when keydown you can get hold of old value and append it with new value.

```
let keyPressed = true
function onKeyDown(event) {
    if(keyPressed && event.keyCode !== 8)
      {
        keyPressed = false;
        let oldvalue = document.getElementById('input-textbox-id').value;
        document.getElementById('input-textbox-id').value = "http://"+oldvalue
      }

    if(!document.getElementById('input-textbox-id').value)
      {
        keyPressed = true;
      }
     }
```

here is working code.  http://jsbin.com/zoxiwokepi/edit?html,output